# Color does not work sometimes, when using a separate color.ts file in Next.js with Tailwind CSS

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, background-color

This is the first time I am working with Tailwind CSS. When I am using "${selectedColors.bgHover}", the hover does not work. Then I hardcoded the hover color as "hover:bg-gray-200" or "dark:hover:bg-gray-700" instead of using "${selectedColors.bgHover}", and it works. After hardcoding, again I have replaced the hard coded value with "${selectedColors.bgHover}", then it works.

```
            <div
              className={`flex items-center py-2 rounded-lg ${selectedColors.bgHover} cursor-pointer${
                selectedLeftNavbarItem === "home"
                  ? " bg-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-700"
                  : ""
              } ${expanded ? "px-4" : "justify-center"}`}
              onClick={() => handleLeftNavbarItemClick("home")}
            >
              <FaHome className="text-lg text-blue-500" />
              {expanded && <span className="ml-2 font-bold">Home</span>}
            </div>
            
          </div>
```

color.ts

```
import { useTheme } from "next-themes";

function useSelectedColors() {
  const { theme } = useTheme();
  const isDarkMode = theme === "dark";

  const selectedColors = {
    bgHover: isDarkMode ? "dark:hover:bg-gray-700" : "hover:bg-gray-200",
  };

  return selectedColors;
}

export default useSelectedColors;
```

[example of the hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4tUC.png)

Why is that? And how I solve it?